# How to check User Activity value repeatedly in website

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I'm building a website using ASP.NET. It's a game which I connect two users randomly to play with each other.

What I need to do is when one of these two players logs out or has been inactive for a certain time, I finish the game and send the other player to some page to tell him or her the game is over.

My problem is I can't figure out how to track the user status every while. I know that ASP.NET has (LastActivityDate), but how can I check this value repeatedly every 30 seconds for example?

Answer (score 1):

lets say you have 2 users

each user *pings the server*  ( ajax) every 2 sec [using javascript's `setInterval`] and increase a counter - or set a new time in the `Application` or `Cache` )  - *global accessed objects*

once in a while - you scan those structures - and if the value ( lets say of DateTime) - is larger by X - so someone has stopeed sending pings - and thats how you know that someone has gone.

Answer (score 1):

You should use jQuery or another Javascript library for using ajax simply. You need also to use 'setInterval' function that will verify that user still active.

Links:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp

Comment: Can you give a hint of the way I should implement that in this way?